# There is no ViewData error with no solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I get this error

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CategoryList'.
```

I have read all the other posts on stackoverflow about this problem yet I can't fix it! It should work because I have created a test mvc3 project doing the exact same thing and there is no problem.

Here's the controller code:

```
    public ViewResult EditProduct(Guid id)
    {
        var product = _repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);

        ViewBag.CategoryList = _repository.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString(), Selected = productToEdit.ID == x.ID }) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;

        return View(product);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditProduct(Product productToEdit)
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryList = _repository.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString(), Selected = productToEdit.ID == x.ID }) as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _repository.SaveProduct(productToEdit);
            TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} has been saved", productToEdit.Title);
            return RedirectToAction("Product");
        }          

        return View(productToEdit);
    }
```

Here's the razor code:

```
    <span class="field">
         @Html.DropDownList("CategoryList");
    </span>
```

I have also tried:

```
    <span class="field">
         @Html.DropDownList("CategoryList", ViewBag.CategoryList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>);
    </span>
```

As a side note, the `<span>` is inside a `AjaxBeginForm` with other calls to the Model within as well.

I have tried putting a _0 in front of CategoryList. That shouldn't be a problem either. I know I don't even need to have that second parameter type casting the list because my test project doesn't need it. I know I don't have to use a ViewModel because again, this should work, MvcMusicStore shows it working.

Why on earth does it not work me?

Thanks for any help, I would appreciate sample code to make it easier for me to understand.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ViewModels:

```
public class ProductViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectItems { get; set; }
    public Guid SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

use that in an ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult CreateProduct()
{
    var vm = new ProductViewModel()
        {
            SelectItems = _repository.Categories.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString() })
        };

    return View("Create", vm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Html.DropDownListFor`.and you must pass CategoryList via `ViewData`.try following :

```
<span class="field">
         @Html.DropDownListFor(e=>e.Category , (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["CategoryList"]);
</span>
```

and in the controller :

```
ViewData["CategoryList"] = _repository.Categories.Select(x =>
new SelectListItem { 
Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString(), Selected = productToEdit.ID == x.ID }) 
as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
```

Comment: It says: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Category'. And even if I change that e.Category to "CategoryList" it doesn't work

Comment: I get this error now if I have it all correct: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name

Comment: in which line ? did you changed DropDownList to DropDownListFor?

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CategoryID.ToString(), (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CategoryList"]); and it points specifically at ViewData

Comment: remove ToString() from lambada expression.it will confuse the compiler to pick wrong overload.

Comment: I don't understand what that lambda expression is for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20835/discussion-between-behnam-esmaili-and-no1-melman)

Comment: The ViewData item that has the key 'CategoryID' is of type 'System.Guid' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'. is the error now

Answer (score 0):

I have got this far.

I call the View EditProduct from a `ViewResult CreateProduct()`

So I guess I have to pass the ViewBag through that! I thought it go initialised throught EditProduct?!

Code:

```
    public ViewResult CreateProduct()
    {
        ViewBag.CategoryList = _repository.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString() });
        return View("EditProduct", new Product());
    }
```

I'm guessing this works!